# Windows registry debug

Tags: registry

Is there any way to monitor/debug changes made by an installation to the OS registry? I'm aware of Process Monitor but I look for something that I can
run in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many tools can do that. Regshot, InstallWatch Pro, InCtrl5 are some of them widely used. Get one that fits you well and use it.

From Windows itself, you could use **WMIC** to track changes using the **RegistryKeyChangeEvent** class. You would have to create a **WqlEventQuery** object and use the **ManagementEventWatcher** to watch over these events. When a change occurs, the **EventArrived** of the **ManagementEventWatcher** class is activated.

There are disadvantages to this:

"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" and "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" are not supported.

WMI event does not return the changed value and changed type; it only detects the change itself.

Comment: Thank you. But does the OS itself offer something similar ?

Comment: I have updated the answer.